# Can you add a class to multiple elements in a single line of code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My current code requires 3 lines of code to give these charts their animation. is there a way to define multiple elements in one line of code, something like this? I'm trying to clean up my code and make it easier for others to understand and the less clutter the better.

```
$('#container1,container2,container3').addClass('animated zoomInDown');
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    Highcharts.chart('container1', {
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
            type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'What grade are you in?'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                    style: {
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Percentage',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [{
                name: '9th',
                y: 0
            }, {
                name: '10th',
                y: 16.7,
                sliced: true,
                selected: true
            }, {
                name: '11th',
                y: 25
            }, {
                name: '12th',
                y: 58.3
            }]
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="container1" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<script>
  $('#container1').addClass('animated zoomInDown');
</script>
<div id="container2" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<script>
  $('#container2').addClass('animated zoomInDown');
</script>
<div id="container3" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<script>
  $('#container3').addClass('animated zoomInDown');
</script>
```

Comment: You are selecting `<div id="container1">`,  `<container2>`, and `<container3>` elements. The `#` does not get applied to all the elements. https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For selecting multiple elements with an id that has a common prefix try this:

```
$('[id^=container]')
```

and then you use the `addClass` method.

Comment: Is there a way to define that it should have a number after it? I already have a div with the id "container", I made these separate numbered containers for the graphs specifically.

Comment: @Anthony probably the most convenient for checking if `id` finishes with a number is to filter, take a look at https://jsfiddle.net/maio/2wrma9s4/

Comment: Is there a way to select multiple id's using this method, say i want to select these containers along with an "img" id?

Comment: you can chain the selector with a comma `$('[id^=container], img')`

Answer (score 1):

You may pass multiple selectors for jQuery to search on and all the found elements will be placed into a "wrapped set" of elements that then can be acted on as a group.

**But (of course) the selectors must be correct:**

`$('#container1,container2,container3')`

needs to be:

`$('#container1,#container2,#container3')`

or even:

`$('id^=container')`

But, the point is that you have to remember the old addage: "*Garbage in...garbage out.*"

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#container1 ,#container2, #container3, #containerN").addClass('animated zoomInDown');
```

Answer (score 0):

Plain JS example for the sake of it:

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('[id]')].forEach(el => el.classList.add('tomato'));
```

```css
.tomato {
  color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo">Foo</div>
<div id="bar">Bar</div>
<div id="baz">Baz</div>
```